# How to avoid linking unnecessary static libraries with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a small project with 2 static libraries and a single executable.

- `utils`: a static library.
- `lib1`: a static library. Some of the functions in `lib1` uses `utils` code, but most don't.
- `main` : an executable that uses functions from `lib1`, that don't use code from `utils`.

In a simple Visual Studio project, `main` would only link `lib1`. But since lib1 needs some of utils' `target_include_directories` to compile, the cmake code for `lib1` contains a `target_link_libraries` call:

utils CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_include_directories(utils INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}) # lib1 needs this
```

lib1: CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(lib1 PRIVATE utils) # some of lib1 code uses utils
```

main: CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE lib1) # this causes utils to link as well
```

The problem is that in the generated project, `main` contains 2 dependencies instead of 1. If I manually remove `utils` from the list of dependencies, everything works just fine.

But right now I have to compile utils in order to compile main.

What is the right approach to have `main` link only with `lib1`? And more generally, how to avoid linking unnecessary static libraries with cmake?

Comment: Libraries named `utils` or `misc` often becomes a dumping ground for too much _nice stuff_. I recommend splitting `utils` up in smaller parts - and name the resulting libraries appropriately. That way it'll be easier to not just keep adding functions to them.

Comment: @TedLyngmo this is just a dummy case for the question sake. This usage pattern appears a lot in a large project I started working on. Trying to see how this can be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, i've seen that a lot too. The "solution" has usually be to split the bloated library. You could start out easy. Split it in 2 parts so that only the functions `lib1` uses are left in the library. If that doesn't make it easier to give the remaining functions a good library name, split again.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that static libraries are nothing more than archives of object files. Linking with a static library is just like linking with the object files themselves.

This leads to two things:

1. Static libraries are not linked themselves;
2. And you need to link with all dependencies of the static libraries.

For your project, the `main` program *must* link with both the static libraries.

Comment: I don't understand *why* I have to link both. The fact is that my project compiles just fine without the utils dependency, because no code path leads to one of its object files.

Comment: Ideally, I would be able to find a command that adds the additional include directories to lib1, without creating a dependency.

Comment: @EladMaimoni That's not really possible. Your best bet is what Ted suggests, split the libraries into smaller parts. With tools like CMake the dependencies are easy to handle, and there's no run-time penalties by having many small static libraries.

Comment: Please check my answer. It currently works. Are you claiming it will break on some scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. In my limited tests it works both for MSVC and GCC.

Basically, instead of using `target_link_libraries` inside lib1's CMakeLists.txt, I use the following function:

```
function(add_interface_includes target_library src_library)    
    get_target_property(library_interface_includes ${src_library} INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
    set_target_properties(${target_library} PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${library_interface_includes}")
endfunction()
```

When I write `add_interface_includes(lib1 utils)` I basically mimic the behavior of  `target_link_libraries` without creating linker dependencies. When `main` links `lib1`, it will only link `utils` if I specify it explicitly.

Comment: This will add the include directories of `src_library` as a dependency of `target_library`. This will work fine if all ever needed are the header files of the `src_libraries`. But will stop working if `target_library` is modified to depend on the actual `src_library`. I think you need to create two "util" libraries: One *header-only*, and one static library for actual linking. Then you make the header-only library a dependency of both the `lib1` and `util` linker-library. It's a nicer, more portable, and IMO correct solution.

Comment: Actually this works even though utils is not a header only library. And this behavior is familiar to me with MSVC: you link only what you use (directly or indirectly). But the fact that the some library1 uses library2 does not matter if your code don't use library2 (directly or indirectly through library1). It might be more fragile - yes, but I prefer not to pay for what I don't have to.

Comment: @EladMaimoni Ok, `util` is not a true header only lib but the functions you use in `lib1` only uses the header only part of `util`? If so, I'd split `util` and make a true header only lib of those parts. That makes using the libraries easier for everyone too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo No, lib1 uses non header only functions from util. But main don't use these specific functions from lib1. there are no header only functions in any of the libraries. And still, as long as main code don't use any of utils code indirectly through lib1, it doesn't have to link it.
BTW - this works for GCC as well.

Comment: Aha, I think I finally understand. That took awhile :-) I would probably split `lib1` up in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes that is the ideal thing to do. But for now I would be pleased with less link dependencies and less compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

If some features of the `utils` library can be used by getting only headers, then I would make the header-only target.

`utils` CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(utils_hdr INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(utils_hdr INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(utils STATIC *.c)
target_link_libraries(utils PUBLIC utils_hdr)
```

`lib1` CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(lib1 PRIVATE utils_hdr)
```

`main` CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE lib1)
```

Comment: utils isn't header only. but thanks.